# How to safely escape the title attribute

Tags: escaping

I'm going through some training on internationalization and escaping data.  But I feel stuck with escaping the title attribute.  I have the following code in a helper function...

```
   echo '<h2 class="m-title">';
    printf(
        esc_html__('%s','tn'),
            '<a href="'.esc_url(get_permalink()).'" title="'.the_title_attribute().'">
            '. esc_html(get_the_title()).'
            </a> 
        '
    );
    echo '</h2>';
```

Everything appears to be working fine with it, except the title attribute.  The output looks like this....

```
Hello world! Hello world!
```

Because the DOM is loading the following:

```
<h2 class="m-title">
  Hello world!
  <a href="http://local.dev.site/mysite/?p=26" title="">
  Hello world!
  </a> 
</h2>
```

What I am doing wrong with calling `the_title_attribute()`?  [According to the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title_attribute/), its already escaped.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: The title is showing up early because all the `the_something()` functions output the results immediately. You need a `get_the_something()` function so it can be processed by `esc_html__()` and `print_f()`.

Comment: Yes, there is, re-read the docs for `the_title_attribute`, there's a parameter on whether to return or echo the result

Comment: You beat me to it.  I just posted that below.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some screen readers read the title attribute plus the link text - so those visitors would hear "Hello world! Hello world!" - so unless your real title attribute is different than the link text and provides additional context to users of screen readers, you may wish to just not use the title attribute.

Or, you should be able to rewrite everything so that instead of echoing you have something like

```
<?php // your other code here ?>
<h2 class="m-title">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
</h2>
```

This way you're mixing HTML and PHP but it allows you to immediately output both, so that `the_title_attribute()` is outputting in the right spot and not before everything else is parsed. You can add the additional `esc_html__()` call wrapped within each set of PHP tags but it's not clear why those would be needed for fields like `the_permalink()`.

Comment: I am now seeing, based on background research and now your thoughts on this very specific topic. this is the way to go.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that there's a missing `echo` statement in the `href` attribute for the permalink

Comment: Fixed above. :)

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to also add something I overlooked on the use of `the_title_attribute`.  There are [$args](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title_attribute/) that can be applied. So in the event of returning the title one could simply set echo to false like so...

```
    echo '<h2 class="m-title">';
    printf(
        esc_html__('%s','tn'),
            '<a href="'.esc_url(get_permalink()).'" title="'.the_title_attribute(['echo' => false]).'">
            '. esc_html(get_the_title()).'
            </a> 
            '
    );
    echo '</h2>';
```

This is what I was originally looking for, but sense I am not doing a good job in providing a translatable string through [esc_html__()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html__/), it would make more sense to simply echo the title, as shown in the selected answer.